# SQL Statement to Add to Every Field

Tags: sql

My table, for example:

```
Table money
_uid____cash_
0   |   500
1   |   740
2   |   800
```

In MySQL, is there a way to write a statement that adds 100 to every entry in the cash column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
UPDATE money
SET cash = cash + 100;
```